# Obtain the AWS SQS Message Receipt Handle from the forwarded aws-sqsd daemon Elastic Beanstalk requests

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-sqs

Anyone know how to get the message receipt handle from the aws-sqsd worker daemon (When the request is forwarded to the application)? Basically, the aws-sqsd drives the work item pickup, and then I want to use boto to potentially extend the message visibility (so I don't have the message itself in boto, so m.receipt_handle does not help). In the headers of the aws-sqsd request, it provides almost all that info, except the receipt_handle...

---

We are trying to extend the current solution we have in place for sqs message handling. The worker instances in our Elastic Beanstalk environments are setup to use the aws-sqsd daemon for message retrieval/forwarding to our application.

Currently trying to determine the best means of obtaining the message receipt handle from the aws-sqsd daemon to then allow us to extend the message visibility timeout using Boto after the fact (which requires the receipt handle).

As it stands, the aws-sqsd provides the following information in the request headers... but sadly the message receipt handle is not provided...)

```
Headers:
Host: localhost
X-Aws-Sqsd-Sent-At: 2015-12-02T03:46:35Z
User-Agent: aws-sqsd/2.0
X-Aws-Sqsd-Queue: 
X-Aws-Sqsd-Path:
X-Forwarded-For: 127.0.0.1
X-Aws-Sqsd-First-Received-At: 2015-12-02T03:46:35Z
X-Aws-Sqsd-Msgid: 
X-Aws-Sqsd-Receive-Count: 1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Aws-Sqsd-Sender-Id: 
Content-Length: 298
X-Real-Ip: 127.0.0.1
```

Would be very helpful to also include:

- X-Aws-Sqsd-Message-Receipt-Handle

Currently using:

- X-Aws-Sqsd-Queue
- X-Aws-Sqsd-Msgid

How could I go about getting that important piece of information?

- This touches on an overall limitation I have been encountering, it is very hard to obtain metadata for instances/envs within an instance (e.g. 'region', which requires using the ec2-metadata tool / boto.utils.get_instance_metadata(), pulling out the placement/availability zone and then doing string manipulation for the region... why is 'region' not provided... same with 'worker_queue_url'... have to get that from the message headers itself (header parsing).

Comment: Anyone have any ideas/insights?

Comment: There's an [open issue for this in github](https://github.com/aws/elastic-beanstalk-roadmap/issues/190) - please vote for it to encourage the maintainers to add this feature